# Trying to create new column that has the dataframes name through for loop?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and I want to create a new column in each of those dataframes that is the name of the dataframe, which I also have in another list. I'm not sure why but it ends up creating a new dataframe that only consists of the last dataframe in my list.

```
schema <- "x"
table_prefix <- "results_"
geos <- district %>% filter(geo != "geo")

for (geo in geos){
  tables <- paste0(schema, ".", table_prefix, geo)
  queries <-   paste("SELECT * FROM", tables)
}


i = 1
df_list <- list()
for (x in queries){
  name <- substr(x, 40, nchar(x))
  df_list[i] <- name
  assign(name, dbGetQuery(con, x))
  i = i + 1
}

dfs <- lapply(df_list, get)

i = 1
for (x in dfs){
  x$geo <- df_list[i]
  i = i + 1
} 


full_df <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
```

This ends up giving me a new dataframe called 'x' that has the contents of the last dataframe in my list with the new column I want. How can I get it so all the dataframes get a new column with their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:length(dfs)){
  dfs[[i]]$geo <- df_list[i]
}
```